# Probability that at least two of three uniform random variables~[0 1.5] add up to >2

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

There's a problem I've been stuck on for a while regarding the sum of two uniformly distributed, independent random variables. The problem goes like this:

You find some old batteries in a drawer. They produce the voltage Xi. Assume that Xi i.i.d. and **uniformly distributed in [0, 1.5].**

You pick **three batteries.** **What is the probability that at least two of them have voltages that add up to more than 2V?**

I've been able to find the probability that any set of two of them add up to more than 2, but I can't figure out how to set up the rest. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could make a 3D sketch on a cube of side $1.5$ of the desired region and find its volume... However they're old possibly means the distributions are neither uniform nor independent :(

Comment: I'd probably find the distribution of the maximum of the three, then condition the maximum of the other two on the value of the maximum, and find the probability that the sum exceeds two volts.

Comment: @Macavity: It's not clear that the source of the problem is concerned with its physical verisimilitude.  But I like the general graphical approach.  I'm not sure why I didn't recommend it...

Comment: @BrianTung  One can hope the contextual stories are more plausible if not realistic.

Comment: @BrianTung Do you think you could expand a little more on your original suggestion? I'm having a really hard time figuring out of the setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's rescale to $[0,1]$ and a sum of $\frac43$ to make it a bit easier.

Fleshing out Brian's suggestion:

At least one pair sums to at least $\frac43$ if the maximum pair sums to at least $\frac43$.

The maximum voltage has cumulative distribution function $x^3$ and thus probability density function $3x^2$. Conditional on $x$, the second-highest voltage has cumulative distribution function $\frac{y^2}{x^2}$ and thus probability density function $\frac{2y}{x^2}$. For the sum to be at least $\frac43$, the maximum has to be at least $\frac23$. The desired probability is

$$
\int_\frac23^1\mathrm dx\,3x^2\int_{\frac43-x}^x\mathrm dy\frac{2y}{x^2}=6\int_\frac23^1\mathrm dx\int_{\frac43-x}^x\mathrm dy\,y\;,
$$

which by the way can also be interpreted as

$$
3!\int_\frac23^1\mathrm dx\int_{\frac43-x}^x\mathrm dy\int_0^y\mathrm dz\;,
$$

with a fixed order for the three variables and a factor $3!$ for the possible orders, another way to set up the integration. In any case, the result is

$$
6\int_\frac23^1\mathrm dx\int_{\frac43-x}^x\mathrm dy\,y=3\int_\frac23^1\mathrm dx\left(x^2-\left(\frac43-x\right)^2\right)=\frac49\;.
$$

Comment: Thanks! This looks to answer the question. Just one thing: how did you derive that conditional cdf for the second order statistic? I am fairly new to probability and I can't seem to follow that step.

Comment: @JordanField: Given that the maximum is $x$, the other two are distributed uniformly over $[0,x]$; rescale to $[0,1]$ and use the cumulative distribution function for the maximum of two.